# AWS Kinesis Data Analytics SQL error message: java.lang.AssertionError: type mismatch: type1: DECIMAL(18, 6) type2:7: DOUBLE

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I am unable to figure out why I am getting this error with AWS Kinesis Data Analytics.

SQL error message: java.lang.AssertionError: type mismatch: type1: DECIMAL(18, 6) type2:7: DOUBLE

I am attempting to do some aggregations over a STAGGERED window. However there seems to be some disconnect between data types.

Here is my SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM "FARM_SPECIFIC_YIELD_AGGREGATION"
  (UTC_TIME BIGINT,
  ASSET_ID BIGINT,
  FARM_ID BIGINT,
  SIGNAL_NAME VARCHAR(60),
  SIGNAL_VALUE  DECIMAL(18, 6),
  ASSET_TYPE VARCHAR(32),
  IN_OPERATIONAL_WINDOW BOOLEAN NOT NULL, -- boolean flag indicating whether the event time falls between sunrise and sunset for the associated farm
  IS_AGGREGATE BOOLEAN NOT NULL);

CREATE OR REPLACE PUMP "FARM_SPECIFIC_YIELD_PUMP" AS INSERT INTO "FARM_SPECIFIC_YIELD_AGGREGATION"
SELECT STREAM
  SRC.UTC_TIME AS UTC_TIME,
  SRC.FARM_ID AS ASSET_ID,
  SRC.FARM_ID AS FARM_ID,
  CASE SRC.SIGNAL_NAME 
  WHEN 'generation.na.dtn' THEN 'specific_yield-avg.farm.10m'
  ELSE NULL
  END AS SIGNAL_NAME,
  SUM(SRC.SIGNAL_VALUE) / SUM(FM.CAPACITY) AS SIGNAL_VALUE,
  SRC.ASSET_TYPE AS ASSET_TYPE,
  SRC.IN_OPERATIONAL_WINDOW AS IN_OPERATIONAL_WINDOW,
  FALSE AS IS_AGGREGATE
  FROM "SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001" AS SRC
  JOIN FARM_METADATA AS FM
  ON SRC.ASSET_ID = FM.ASSET_ID
  WHERE (SRC.SIGNAL_VALUE IS NOT NULL AND SRC.SIGNAL_VALUE > 0 AND SRC.SIGNAL_VALUE <= FM.CAPACITY)
  AND SRC.SIGNAL_NAME IN ('generation.na.dtn')
  WINDOWED BY STAGGER (
  PARTITION BY SRC.UTC_TIME, SRC.FARM_ID, SRC.SIGNAL_NAME, SRC.ASSET_TYPE, SRC.IN_OPERATIONAL_WINDOW
  RANGE INTERVAL '10' MINUTE);
```

I attempted to cast the values, but it did not work correctly. Maybe the SUM() aggregation may be a problem.

If I cast the value I get the following error:
SQL error message: java.lang.AssertionError: RexInputRef index 8 out of range 0..7

These are the data types. 
SIGNAL_VALUE is DECIMAL(18, 6)
FM.CAPACITY is DOUBLE

Any help would be appreciated. I think AWS KDA does not have a large presence yet on stack overflow.

Comment: Were you able to figure out what the issue was?  I have a similar error and haven't found a solution yet.